# #SUGBELUX - Session #16 - Sitecore Symposium 2018 Recap

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Local Date/Time:** Thursday October 31th 2018 at 6:00PM

**UTC Date/Time:** Thursday October 31th 2018 at 4:00PM

**Location:** Havenlaan 86C, Brussels, Belgium

**Link to details:** https://www.meetup.com/nl-NL/Sitecore-User-Group-Belgium/events/253339164/

**Who to contact for information:** Ivan Lieckens or Kris Verheire

**Description:**

This session is one of our yearly recurring topics.
As attending the Symposium is time-expensive and as a general a heavy investment, we aim at providing you with all the valueable information that was presented during the Symposium.

We typically provide an insight on the various presented tracks that were attended.
The full agenda will be made available shortly after the Symposium as the actual agenda has just recently been anounced.

Multiple MVP speakers will handle the sessions that were attended or that were discussed in great detail.
This will encompass:
- New features
- Specific cases
- Feature and product evolution and development
- Valuable third party solutions

We kindly refer you to https://symposium.sitecore.com/ where the whole symposium is described in detail.
If there are specifc topics that you would like to have more emphasis on during the recap, do not hesitate to let us know.

We look forward to welcome you to this Symposium recap.

Kind regards,
The SUG BeLux group.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Oct 15 at 16:00

Comment: Updated. Community Bulletin promotion begins on Oct 21 at 16:00